# spinner dependent on another spinner in android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html
I use this link as the base..

I have 3 spinners, first spinner for country , second for states and third for cities.

I had already seen the links on the stackoverflow , but it is not that much proper.

my code is as follows

> public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity
>   {
>
> String state="";
>
> ArrayAdapter adapter1,adapter2;
>      Spinner spinner1,spinner2;
>
> /** Called when the activity is first created. */
>      @Override
>      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>      {
>          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>          setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
> ```
>     spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
>     spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
>
>    adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
>            this, R.array.states_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
>    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
>    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
>    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
>
>
>    if(state.equalsIgnoreCase("Gujarat"))
>    {  
>     adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.rajasthan_array, >android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
>     }
>   if(state == "Rajasthan")
>    {
>     adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.rajasthan_array, >android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
>    }
>
>    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
>    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
>    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
> ```
>
> }
>
> public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
>      {
>
> ```
>    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id)
>    {
>       state=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
>      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The state is " +
>          parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>    }
>    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent)
>    {
>     //    Do nothing.
>    }
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

the bug I found is , I have created all he thing in the onCreate() method..
but I do not find the alternate thing that can I do ...
I don't know why this not work ..

please help if possible

thanks...

Comment: if one spinner enter the Country India , then the second spinner shows the states of India ,.... , but this code do not work somehow

Answer (score 0):

In onSelectItem fill second spinner and so on.

Comment: sorry , but I don't get it ,,
can you please send me the code if possible 
it would be greatfull 
thanks

Comment: Did you get nullPointerExcaptions?

Comment: I got NullPointerEcxeption , FatulException and RuntimeException